# file exists not working in expect script

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script, expect

I'm trying to check if a particular line exists in filename on a host. So only if the particular pattern is found from the grep command a dummy.txt will be created. Then I want to check if dummy.txt exists as a condition and proceed.

But even though dummy.txt is getting created its not being found by the if statement :

```
if {[file exists $fileName] }
```

and the control is transferred to the else block.  What could be the reason?  Is there any easier method to achieve what I'm trying to ?

```
 set Host [lindex $argv 0 ]
 spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no userid@$Host
 expect "*assword*"
 send "password\n"
 expect "+"
 send "cd path/that/contains/filename\n"
 expect "*$*"
 send "pwd\n"
 set fileName dummy.txt
 send {grep '\[abc\]' filename | wc -l | { read line; [ "$line" != "0" ] && echo "$line"> dummy.txt; }}
 send "\n"
 expect "+"
 send {grep 'xyz' filename | wc -l | { read line; [ "$line" != "0" ] && echo "$line"> dummy.txt; }}
 send "\n"
 expect "+"
 send "chmod 777 dummy.txt\n"
 if {[file exists $fileName] } {

   send {printf "\nabc xyz already exists"} 
   send "\n"
   expect "+"
   send "ls -l\n"
   expect "+"
   send "rm dummy.txt\n"
   expect "+"
   send "ls -l\n"
   expect "+"
        send "exit\n"
  } else {
        send {printf "cannot find $fileName"}
   send "\n"
   expect "+"
   send {printf "\n[abc]\nxyz\n" >> filename}
   send "\n"
   expect "+"
   send "cat filename\n"
   expect "+"
    send "exit\n"

    }
```

Comment: Instead of this `wc | read ...` you could simply check grep's return code (0 = match found, see `man grep`).

Answer (score 1):

`if {[file exists $fileName] }` will check whether the file exists on the local system
(the one where `expect` is running), but the conditionally created file will be on the remote host
(the one that the script logs into with `ssh`) if it exists. 
Also, `filename` is `dummy`, but the conditionally created file is `dummy.txt`.

Comment: Sorry scott that was a typo. Its dummy.txt everywhere. If its checking on the remote machine then how do I get it to check on the host ? I'm trying to automate the process of adding particular lines to a file, but at the same time if those lines already exist I don't want duplicate entries, which is why I'm using grep and dummy.txt

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo in the question. But, as long as you're editing the question, you should make it clearer. I don't fully understand your comment. If you want to do something conditionally on the remote host based on condition(s) on the remote host, just think of it as a shell script and use shell logic; e.g., `send {grep -q xyz filename || echo xyz >> filename}`.

Comment: I need to add some content say, xyz abc to the file filename on the remote host. But I want to check if those xyz abc already exists in filename. to check this I'm using send {grep '\[abc\]' filename | wc -l | { read line; [ "$line" != "0" ] && echo "$line"> dummy.txt; }}
 send "\n"
 expect "+"
 send {grep 'xyz' filename | wc -l | { read line; [ "$line" != "0" ] && echo "$line"> dummy.txt; }}
 send "\n" So if xyz abc exists in filename a new file dummy.txt is created. So if dummy.txt exists on the remote that'll mean xyz and abc are present in filename and the script need not add them again

Comment: I know its seems a bit lengthy but I couldn't think of a simpler way to accomplish this since I've to use interaction. If you can suggest a solution to check for the file on the remote host or a simpler way to make this entire thing work, it'd be great :)

Comment: `send {[ -f dummy.txt ] && echo "xyz abc" >> filename}`. Or read my most recent comment again.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks ! But I don't seem to understand how or where this would in my expect script. Could you please explain ?

Comment: What do you not understand? You're already doing stuff on the remote host conditionally by sending `[…] && …`. Just adapt that to do what you want -- as I illustrated in my last comment.